# Create jQuery when create a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am searching a way it can create jquery script when creating a new element.

Here is what I've done

```
<div id = "content">
content
</div>

<script>
$('#content').click(function(event) {
  $('#content').append('<div id='+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) +'> 123 </div>');
});

// dynamically create click function? 
$('#randomNumber').click(function(event) {
    console.log("Random id");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to, since you can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which applies to your current and future elements, like this:

```
$("#content").on("click", "div", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

This essentially creates a `click` handler for all `div`s existent or not yet existent inside `#content` and the handler logs the `id` of `this`.

And your other handler of

```
$('#content').click(function(event) {
  $('#content').append('<div id='+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) +'> 123 </div>');
});
```

creates such `div`s. Just make sure you do not duplicate `id`s, as that would lead to [invalid HTML](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really), which is punished when it comes to SEO scores.

Comment: This is great! I am searching this way!

Comment: @CodaChang, I am happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('#content').click(function(event) {
  var randDiv = $('<div id='+ Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) +'> 123 </div>').appendTo('#content');
  // dynamically create click function? 
  randDiv.click(function(event) {
    console.log("Random id");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that generates a random number like that :

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

And use it when you append a new div with a random id.

**EDIT : Here is a jsbin https://jsbin.com/cimusoxale/edit?html,js,console,output**